# Package does not exist when running H2 under SBT

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, h2

I have a Scala project using H2, in which I create a trigger using the following SQL:

```
  s"""
     | CREATE TRIGGER $triggerName
     |    BEFORE UPDATE ON $inTable
     |    FOR EACH ROW
     |    AS $$$$org.h2.api.Trigger create() { return new org.project.database.LoggingTrigger("$onModifyColumn", "$logValueOfColumn", "$storeInColumn"); } $$$$;
   """
```

When I run my tests and/or application under IntellIJ, the trigger works as intended (both being created successfully and subsequently having the desired effect). When I try to run the application or tests under SBT from the command line (outside of IntelliJ), I get the following error:

```
[error]  org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "/org/h2/dynamic/trigger/TRIGGER_LXQX2FJ1UVEBCJ1GWRKFJQVTHEZYZTRB.java:6: error: package org.h2.api does not exist
[error]      public static org.h2.api.Trigger create() { return new org.project.database.LoggingTrigger(""last_error_message"", ""hostname"", ""last_error_host""); }
[error]                              ^
[error]  

/org/h2/dynamic/trigger/TRIGGER_LXQX2FJ1UVEBCJ1GWRKFJQVTHEZYZTRB.java:6: error: package org.project.database does not exist
    [error]      public static org.h2.api.Trigger create() { return new org.project.database.LoggingTrigger(""last_error_message"", ""hostname"", ""last_error_host""); }
           ^
[error]  2 errors
[error]  " [42000-187] (DbException.java:345)
[error] org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
[error] org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
[error] org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
[error] org.h2.util.SourceCompiler.throwSyntaxError(SourceCompiler.java:364)
[error] org.h2.util.SourceCompiler.javaxToolsJavac(SourceCompiler.java:288)
[error] org.h2.util.SourceCompiler$1.findClass(SourceCompiler.java:150)
[error] org.h2.util.SourceCompiler.getClass(SourceCompiler.java:164)
[error] org.h2.util.SourceCompiler.getMethod(SourceCompiler.java:178)
[error] org.h2.schema.TriggerObject.loadFromSource(TriggerObject.java:97)
[error] org.h2.schema.TriggerObject.load(TriggerObject.java:78)
[error] org.h2.schema.TriggerObject.setTriggerAction(TriggerObject.java:136)
[error] org.h2.schema.TriggerObject.setTriggerSource(TriggerObject.java:129)
[error] org.h2.command.ddl.CreateTrigger.update(CreateTrigger.java:117)
[error] org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:78)
[error] org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:254)
[error] org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.execute(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:198)
```

Logging out the value of the `java.class.path` system properties in both contexts produces very different results. From IntelliJ, this is a very long path including all the dependency JARs. From SBT, it's only `C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\bin\sbt-launch.jar`

My guess is that SBT sorts out the classpath for the main process by some different mechanism to IntelliJ. As the application generally runs under SBT, the right dependencies are available on the classpath. However, there is obviously some difference (e.g. the one visible when logging out `java.class.path` above) which prevents the main process from passing on the correct classpath to H2.

It's particularly odd that H2 can't find one of its own packages. `org.h2.api.Trigger` is in the same JAR as the exception type above and the code that's throwing the exception. This dependency is correctly included in the project's Build.scala file.

Answer (score 0):

SBT uses a complicated hierarchy of nested and delegating classloaders to isolate different parts of the build from each other and to control visibility and manage failures.

The the `java.class.path` system property is largely irrelevant here. If you want to understand the classpath / classloader being used here, you'll have to catch this in the debugger and inspect the classloader directly (you should find a chain of `URLClassLoaders` and `DualLoaders`).

> a Scala project using H2

Could you expand on which part of the app "uses" H2 and by what means? I think that will be the key to your problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you have a unnecessary '% "TEST"' in your library dependencies.

You probably have something like this in your build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.3.161" % "TEST"
```

This then causes sbt to fail during compilation; remove the '% "TEST"':

```
libraryDependencies += "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.3.161"
```